# Faiss project not compiling, undefined refferences

Tags: c++, linux, intel-mkl, faiss

I am trying to compile this project in Ubuntu(wsl).
Intel-mkl libraries should be installed (sudo apt install intel-mkl) and faiss has been built and installed without seemingly any issues. However, when I try to build the project using make command, I am met with errors.

CMakeLists

```
project(faiss_clustering)


set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fno-rtti -Wall -pedantic -Wextra -fopenmp")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -g -fsanitize=address")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -g -flto -ftree-vectorize -march=native")


add_executable(faiss_clustering main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(faiss_clustering PRIVATE faiss blas)
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <faiss/Clustering.h>
#include <faiss/IndexFlat.h>
#include <faiss/utils/utils.h>


using namespace std;

struct sfile_info {
    size_t dim;
    size_t count;
    char file_name[256];

    sfile_info(char* p_file_name) {
        strcpy(file_name, p_file_name);
    }
};

float* fvecs_read(sfile_info& fi)
{
    FILE* f = fopen(fi.file_name, "r");
    if (!f) {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not open %s\n", fi.file_name);
        perror("");
        abort();
    }
    int d;
    fread(&d, 1, sizeof(int), f);
    assert((d > 0 && d < 1000000) || !"unreasonable dimension");
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    struct stat st;
    fstat(fileno(f), &st);
    size_t sz = st.st_size;
    assert(sz % ((d + 1) * 4) == 0 || !"weird file size");
    size_t n = sz / ((d + 1) * 4);

    fi.dim = d;
    fi.count = n;
    float* x = new float[n * (d + 1)];
    size_t nr = fread(x, sizeof(float), n * (d + 1), f);
    assert(nr == n * (d + 1) || !"could not read whole file");

    // shift array to remove row headers
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        memmove(x + i * d, x + 1 + i * (d + 1), d * sizeof(*x));

    fclose(f);
    return x;
}

// not very clean, but works as long as sizeof(int) == sizeof(float)
int* ivecs_read(sfile_info& fi) {
    return (int*)fvecs_read(fi);
}

double distance(float* data, float* query, size_t dim)
{
    double dist = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < dim; k++)
    {
        double r = data[k] - query[k];
        dist += r * r;
    }
    return dist;
}


int main()
{
    int numberOfEMIterations = 20;
    size_t numberOfClusters = 1000;

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////// READ DATA
    sfile_info fi_base("../../sift/sift_base.fvecs");
    sfile_info fi_learn("../../sift/sift_learn.fvecs");
    sfile_info fi_query("../../sift/sift_query.fvecs");
    sfile_info fi_groundtruth("../../sift/sift_groundtruth.ivecs");

    float* mass = fvecs_read(fi_base);
    float* massL = fvecs_read(fi_learn);
    float* massQ = fvecs_read(fi_query);
    int* massQA = ivecs_read(fi_groundtruth);

    assert(fi_base.dim == fi_query.dim || !"query does not have same dimension as base set");
    assert(fi_base.dim == fi_learn.dim || !"learn does not have same dimension as base set");
    assert(fi_query.count == fi_groundtruth.count || !"incorrect number of ground truth entries");


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////// PROCESS CLUSTERING

    faiss::ClusteringParameters cp;
    cp.niter = numberOfEMIterations;
    cp.verbose = true; // print out per-iteration stats

    faiss::IndexFlatL2 index(fi_learn.dim);
    faiss::Clustering kMeans(fi_learn.dim, numberOfClusters, cp);
    kMeans.train(fi_learn.count, massL, index);

    // Print first ten centroids
    int print_center_count = 10;
    for (int c = 0; c < numberOfClusters; c++)
    {
        if (print_center_count-- == 0) break;
        for (int d = 0; d < fi_learn.dim; d++) {
            std::cout << kMeans.centroids[c * fi_learn.dim + d] << " ";    
        }
        std::cout << c << "\n";
    }
  
}
```

Errors:

```
kudlic@LAPTOP-FUCA8DQ5:/mnt/d/codes/AVD/AVD/faiss_clustering/build$ make
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable faiss_clustering
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libfaiss.a(VectorTransform.cpp.o): in function `(anonymous namespace)::eig(unsigned long, double*, double*, int)':
VectorTransform.cpp:(.text+0x176a): undefined reference to `dsyev_'
/usr/bin/ld: VectorTransform.cpp:(.text+0x17e4): undefined reference to `dsyev_'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libfaiss.a(VectorTransform.cpp.o): in function `faiss::ITQMatrix::train(long, float const*)':
VectorTransform.cpp:(.text+0x43d4): undefined reference to `dgesvd_'
/usr/bin/ld: VectorTransform.cpp:(.text+0x4606): undefined reference to `dgesvd_'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libfaiss.a(VectorTransform.cpp.o): in function `faiss::OPQMatrix::train(long, float const*)':
VectorTransform.cpp:(.text+0x6a7c): undefined reference to `sgesvd_'
/usr/bin/ld: VectorTransform.cpp:(.text+0x6b63): undefined reference to `sgesvd_'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libfaiss.a(utils.cpp.o): in function `faiss::matrix_qr(int, int, float*)':
utils.cpp:(.text+0x86b): undefined reference to `sgeqrf_'
/usr/bin/ld: utils.cpp:(.text+0x93d): undefined reference to `sgeqrf_'
/usr/bin/ld: utils.cpp:(.text+0x9a5): undefined reference to `sorgqr_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/faiss_clustering.dir/build.make:97: faiss_clustering] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/faiss_clustering.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

If I try to go to VectorTransform.cpp in vscode and hover over one of the problematic functions, there seems to be only declaration, as these seem to be intel-mkl functions.
[image]

I first tried building and installing faiss library in windows directories, where the project is. I then tried to build and install it again in linux user directory, in hopes it might fix it, alas to no avail.

Do you have any ideas what steps I should take to resolve the issue?
If I forgot any info, tell me and I will add it in.

Comment: Your first step is to determine which libraries provide the symbols reported in the link failure error messages. Once you determine that, it should be fairly clear how to modify your build script to make sure that everything gets linked correctly. Have you tried locating the libraries where those symbols are defined? What did you find?

Comment: I suspect you want to look at [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBLAS.html](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBLAS.html) and / or [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindLAPACK.html](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindLAPACK.html) and the `BLAS_LIBRARIES` and `LAPACK_LIBRARIES` variables I am not sure which one of these has the library that implements the missing symbols.

Comment: @drescherjm You are a godsend, adding snippet from lapack page helped.
```
# Set BLA_VENDOR to Intel10_64lp
set(BLA_VENDOR Intel10_64lp)
find_package(LAPACK)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified on:
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindLAPACK.html
Adding following snippet to CMakeLists solves the issue

```
set(BLA_VENDOR Intel10_64lp) 
find_package(LAPACK)
```